# Fail to install mpl_toolkits.basemap on Mac Python 3.6

Tags: macos, python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap, map-projections

I'm using Python3.6 on a Mac, I need to import Basemap to draw a map. But after I tried to install mpl_toolkits.basemap for many many times, I still failed. Any suggestion? Need your help guys. Thanks. I'm sure I have use pip3 to install geos(0.1.1) and proj(0.1.0).

Comment: Finally, I used Anaconda to provide Python environment, it's much simpler and convenient and installed basemap successfully.